# Smooth moving a 3D Object to another 3D object's surface onCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi2..,

I have a case: that I need to move a 3D object to smoothly move himself(e.g. using lerp) to another 3D object's surface on collision.

This is the script I use on detecting collision.

```
public GameObject targetingObject;
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

    Debug.Log("name: " + collision.gameObject.name);
    Debug.Log("tag: " + collision.gameObject.tag);

}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    targetingObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}

private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("collision is staying");
}
```

This script work as It is and I am able to detect the collision when it happened.
However, I have a bit of difficulites to move the object to "attach" himself to a collided 3D object.

Here is picture of the scenario.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it should be attached once the green sphere touches white sphere? Also how do you move the spheres?

Comment: "The green sphere" should be attached once the "blue Stick" touch the "whiteSphere"

Comment: currently I move them manually in the unity editor.. later it will be with a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can make achieve this by changing parent of green sphere to target object when the collision occurs. Then green sphere will be attached to target and it can move together with its parent(aka target object). Here is the script for it:

```
public GameObject Target;
public GameObject GreenSphere;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{       
    //Since you used Target as a public variable
    if(collision.gameObject == Target)
    {
        GreenSphere.transform.parent = Target.transform;
    }
}
```

Since op does not want to change parent of the object another approach can be calculating distance between spheres and once the distance is equal to `target radius/ 2 + GreenSphere radius/2`, it means objects are touching each other and then they can be considered **attached!**. Here is the script for it:

```
public GameObject target;
float targetSize;
float GreenObjSize;
void Start () {
    targetSize = target.transform.localScale.y / 2;
    GreenObjSize = gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2;
    Debug.Log(targetSize);
}

void Update () {
    if((target.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position).magnitude > (targetSize + GreenObjSize))
    {
        gameObject.transform.position += Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

This script must be attached to `GreenSphere` and will only work if objects are **spheres!**

Comment: Thank you for your answer..,
however I dont want it to make the Greenobject become the parents of the whiteSphere. 

I want the Greensphere to move to the "surface" of the white sphere

Comment: This is what you commented earlier: `"The green sphere" should be attached once the "blue Stick" touch the "whiteSphere"` If you want greensphere to move there and stay on top of it you gotta make it parent once white and green spheres collided.

Comment: is there any other way beside making it as a parent.. ?

Comment: You could use a Fixed Joint https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html  But this will also make it so the white sphere moves when you move the green sphere.

Comment: I am not sure what OP means by saying attached but `FixedJoint` would work too. I edited my answer with a mathematical approach.

Comment: （＾ｖ＾）perhaps i should not say "attached" but "move" will be more appropriate.. my bad.... regardless., your solution should work as a workaround in my case for now..., would love to see some solutions that have more general  (works with even complicated 3D object surface) approach.

Thank youu once again.

Comment: Well more general solution requires more information on what you want to do and how you move the object. If you just want to "move" the objects just move them until they collide with the target. Then you do not need to change any objects' parent.